# cordova-plugin-qrscanner camera not showing

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I installed the Cordova plugin [qrscanner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-qrscanner) and it is working: when I click on a button that triggers the "prepare API", the permission is being asked, then I have two more buttons: one for scan API and one for show API. They are both invoked and I can even scan QR codes. Nevertheless, the camera preview is not showing.
I am not using Ionic.

```
    $scope.prepare = function() {
        console.log("XXX In prepare");
        QRScanner.prepare($scope.done);

    };

    $scope.scan = function() {
        console.log("XXX In scan");
        QRScanner.scan($scope.callback);
    };

    $scope.show = function() {
        console.log("XXX In show");
        QRScanner.show(function(status){
            console.log("XXX Inside");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(status));
        });
        document.body.style.background = 'none transparent !important';
    };

    $scope.done = function(err, status){
        if(err){
            console.log("XXX Done err");
            console.error(err._message);
        } else {
            console.log("XXX Done ok");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(status));
        }
    };

    $scope.callback = function(err, contents){
        if(err){
            console.error(err._message);
        }
        alert('The QR Code contains: ' + contents);
    };
```

Nevertheless, nothing is showing. What's wrong?

Comment: did you ever resolve this?  I am experiencing the same issue.  I have applied `background: none transparent` to the BODY, ION-CONTENT elements (and a slew of others too) but I can't get the scanner to display.  However, the scanner IS active and IS working - I was able to blindly scan a QR Code and get the output to console.  So I know its there and active - but I just can't see it.  I am at a loss of what to do next - is the scanner supposed to be in its own DIV (how would you even do that?)

Comment: any news ? why is this happening ?